# Authorization code in business object or separate handler?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a business object that contains a collection of ACL items and I'm trying to decide whether to put the authorization code in the business object like this:

```
class Foo()
{
  public IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
  public bool HasPermission(string username, FooOperation operation) 
  { 
    // check this Foo's Permissions collection and return the result
  }
}

class FooHandler()
{
  public void SomeOperation(Foo foo)
  {
    if(foo.HasPermission(username, FooPermission.SomeOperation))
    {
      // do some operation
    }
  }
}
```

Or in the object handler like this:

```
class Foo()
{
  public IEnumerable<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

class FooHandler()
{
  public void SomeOperation(Foo foo)
  {
    if(SecurityManager.HasPermission(foo, username, FooPermission.SomeOperation))
    {
      // do some operation
    }
  }
}

class SecurityManager
{
  public HasPermission(Foo foo, string username, FooPermission operation)
  {
    // check foo's Permissions collection and return the result
  }
}
```

**What are the pros and cons of each approach?** Keeping in mind that Permissions collection will be public in either scenario b/c I'm using Entity Framework in my data layer to persist the business objects directly (I'm willing to change this down the road if necessary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is nearest to a MVC Controller structure :)
but for your question, the best practice is to separate authorization from business logic, and you can implement access management as a separated method and call in any where that you need check access permissions. This is very equivalent to Authorize filter in a MVC controller.

Addition description:
I would like to remove ACL collection from business objects and retrieve them from the repository within the SecurityManager class.

Comment: If I place HasPermission() into the SecurityManager class, I would presumably also put GrantPermission() and RemovePermission() there. Should the ACL collection then also be removed from the business object? Why or why not?

Comment: What are the benefits of your suggested approach? It seems to introduce considerable complexity (more handler/manager classes, separate repositories that need to stay sync'd, etc.), and my gut tells me you're right; however, I can't put my finger on the pros.